# Можно ли вручную редактировать эмбед, который был отправлен через вебхук?

Tags: discord

Как изменить вот такие сообщения вебхука без использования ботов?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Да, отправленный вебхук можно изменить без использования ботов. Для этого можно воспользоваться любым сайтом, который это позволяет, например, [этот](https://old.message.style/dashboard). Чтобы изменить вебхук нужно вставить url, который использовался в вебхуке для его же отправки и id сообщения самого вебхука ([как найти id сообщения можно прочитать здесь](https://support.discord.com/hc/ru/articles/206346498-%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-ID-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-)). Далее в оставшихся полях нужно указать новый вебхук, на который изменить старый, но не все данные можно изменить, а именно Username, Avatar URL, id сообщения и url вебхука. Надеюсь помог, если остались вопросы задавай